# View/query to show latest node related to each term in a taxonomy vocabulary

Tags: views, database

I have a node type (stories) which is related to a taxonomy vocabulary (countries).

Each story is related to one country only.

I want to create a view of the latest story from each country, ordered by published date.  I only want 1 story from each country (if there is one).

I looked into doing this with views and couldn't see a way to limit the results to only 1 result per country.

Does anyone have any suggestion how I can do this without writing a custom query?

Thanks,

Comment: you need to add filter and set `Use pager` to 1 item

Comment: Clearly that's not going to work as it's much more complicated than that.  if pager was set to 1 i would only have 1 result.

Answer (score 0):

I think that's the purpose of the module [Views Grouping Row Limit](http://drupal.org/project/views_limit_grouping).